# Proving that number is not supremum of set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have the set $A=\left \{1+\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}  \right \}$
and I am trying to show that $sup(A)\neq 3$.

**Attempt:**

**I)** Showing that 3 is an upper bound of A:

$1+\frac{1}{n}\\\\\Leftrightarrow n>\frac{1}{2}$

which proves that 3 is indeed an upper bound.

**II)** Showing that for a number $3-\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon > 0$
there exists a $1+\frac{1}{n}>3-\varepsilon$:

I do othe algebra and arrive at the following:

if $\varepsilon \geq 2$: $n>\frac{-1}{\varepsilon-2}$

if $\varepsilon < 2$: $n<\frac{-1}{\varepsilon-2}$

Which would indicate that 3-2= 1 would be the supremum of A but clearly sup(A) = 2.

What am I doing wrong here? An explanation is appreciated.

Comment: 'Which would indicate that $3-2=1$ would be the supremum of $A$': it is not clear as to  what you mean by this. $1$ is actually a lower bound for $A$.

Comment: Just cut it to the chase. $3$ is an upper bound, but it is not the supremum (the *least* upper bound) because there are *smaller* upper bounds. (Say, $2$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop yes, but I want to prove this formally and dont understand how to do this...

Comment: What is *informal* in my proof above? The appearance of Greek letters ($\epsilon$) doesn't make a proof more or less formal. This is a common trap: you need to refute an universal sentence ( "Any number less than $3$ is not an upper bound.) To refute it *you only need a counterexample*. In this case, $2$. That is enough and everything else is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: See another post just a few minutes ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520825/is-a-mod-n-mod-q-equiv-a-mod-q. The student knows the statement is false, they've even found a good counterexample, but are still pursuing a "formal proof"... Why oh why???

Comment: @StinkingBishop thank you for the answer. I think I was looking for more of a "one size fits all" way of proving supremums but I guess the proving technique depends on the specific case.

Comment: Of course it depends, and that is why it is good to see many different proofs throughout your math education. Glad to help.